# Nodemon for development environment

Tags: node.js, npm, nodemon, npm-scripts, npm-start

I wanted to know how to use nodemon, and push it to a git repo, and have other developers on the project be able to use nodemon without having to run the command `npm install -g nodemon`. Ideally, I would like all developers on the project to be able to just run `npm start` and nodemon is called whether or not it's installed globally. I've already run `npm install --save-dev nodemon`, and I'm mostly curious if there is a way to get nodemon to be run from within node_modules, in my start command in the scripts section of the package.json file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you install it locally, i.e. without the `-g` flag, it's available in `./node_modules/.bin/nodemon`.  So just configure that path in your `npm start` script.

For example:

```json
"start" : "./node_modules/.bin/nodemon app.js"
```

Comment: Is this how you can install things via npm, and use them via command line without having them stored on your system? I didn't know that, nor could I find anything suggesting this in the npm documentation/nodemon documentation. Thanks, will mark this as the answer.

Comment: @Paul Yes this is ordinary way to do this.
But I would suggest to omit the `"./node_modules/.bin/"` part, because npm commands are also looking at relative node_modules so no need to mention it twice.

Comment: @ArenHovsepyan I've seen that fail before when folks have mucked with their PATH variable, so I say better to be explicit since he's asking specifically about keeping the whole team on the same page.

Comment: @destructi6n, yes.  I'm sorry, I don't know where it was documented, but it's where npm puts command line executables by default on local install, not just nodemon.

Comment: Thank you guys! Very helpful!!